# Sort Order has been change due to DB server movement

Tags: sql-server

We are using SQL server 2012 (service pack 3) and we have recently moved from one server to another. 
After that we have encountered issue SQL sort order problem. We have many report where the order by clause not present. After the movement, the sort order has been changed and the results in the report became different than the actual.

I know the solution by putting Order by clause in ALL stored procedure and View. Since the number of files are huge, it is there anything we can do in the SQL configuration to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 16):

If you don't have an `ORDER BY` clause, the order of the result set is never guaranteed.

- [Connor Cunninghan No Seatbelt Expecting Order Without ORDER BY](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/). In case it gets [archived again](https://web.archive.org/web/20160808070425/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/)
- [Aaron Bertrand showing another exmaple of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982804/determine-latest-row-added-when-no-index-is-present/19983752#19983752)

Also, you mentioned "report". If you are using SSRS or any reporting suite really, they have sort functions within them as well which means you wouldn't have to change any of your procedures or views.